# Update a javascript object using an array for reference

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object;

```
xml
-nutrition
--daily values
--food
---0
----fat=20g
----sodium=
---1
----fat=20g
----sodium=5mg
---2
----fat=20g
----sodium=5mg
-stores
--0
--1
```

I also have a dynamically generated javascript array

```
["xml", "nutrition", "food", 0]
```

How can I update the javascript object based on this array? without typing it manually

```
myobj[array[0]][array[1]][array[2]][array[3]].fat = '30g';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for it.

> It iterates over all given keys and returns the last reference for further use.

```
["xml", "nutrition", "food", 0].reduce(function (r, k) {
    return r[k];
}, myobj).fat = '30g';
```

or ES6

```
["xml", "nutrition", "food", 0].reduce((r, k) => r[k], myobj).fat = '30g';
```